# OAuth making requests against LinkedIn API cause 401 error

Tags: coldfusion, oauth, linkedin-api, coldfusion-9

I am creating an application for a client that integrates with the LinkedIn API. I got through the authentication without too many problems, but everything there is working and now I need to make the actual requests. Primarily I am working in the Share API. I create the HTTP call with the following method:

```
  public any function sendRequest(any req){
    var param = false;
    var headParams = [];
    var bodyParams = [];
    var call = new http(proxyserver='192.168.201.12', proxyport=8888);
    var i = 1;

    call.setUrl(Arguments.req.getRequestUrl());
    call.setMethod(Arguments.req.getMethod());

    getSigner().signRequest(Arguments.req);

    headParams = Arguments.req.getParameters(true);
    bodyParams = Arguments.req.getParameters();

    if(arrayLen(bodyParams)){
      call.addParam(
        type='header',
        name='Authorization',
        value="OAuth#Variables.encoder.encodedParameter(Arguments.req.getParameters(true), true, false, true)#"
      );
    }

    // Header parameters
    if(!arrayLen(bodyParams)){
      for(i=1; i<=arrayLen(headParams); i++){
        param = headParams[i];
        call.addParam(
          type=Arguments.req.getParameterType(),
          name=Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(param.name),
          value=param.value
        );
      }
    }

    // Body parameters (should only be 1)
    if(arrayLen(bodyParams)){
      for(i=1; i<=arrayLen(bodyParams); i++){
        param = bodyParams[i];
        call.addParam(
          type='xml',
          value=param.value
        );
      }
    }
    return call.send().getPrefix();
  }
```

When I sign the request, I use the following method:

```
  public void function signRequest(any req){
    var headParams = Arguments.req.getParameters(true);
    var bodyParams = Arguments.req.getParameters();
    var secret = "#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(getConsumer().getConsumerSecret())#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(Arguments.req.getOAuthSecret())#";
    var base = '';

    params = Variables.encoder.encodedParameter(headParams, true, true);
    params = "#params#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(bodyParams[1].value)#";

    secret = toBinary(toBase64(secret));

    local.mac = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.Mac').getInstance('HmacSHA1');
    local.key = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec').init(secret, local.mac.getAlgorithm());

    base = "#Arguments.req.getMethod()#&";
    base = base & Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(Arguments.req.getRequestUrl());
    base = "#base#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(params)#";
    //writeDump(base) abort;
    local.mac.init(local.key);
    local.mac.update(JavaCast('string', base).getBytes());

    Arguments.req.addParameter('oauth_signature', toString(toBase64(mac.doFinal())), true);
  }
```

I have tried signing it with only the header parameters (usual OAuth params) and include the body parameter (xml string), but everything gives me a 401 error, so I was wondering what I should be using in my base string that gets signed for the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a proper answer to your question, but may help you.

In my case after many unsuccessful tries of using the LinkedIn API with CF8, I finally gave up / didn't have more time for it. Instead of a "proper" integration I've used the [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) Java library. It finally got me going and I didn't encounter any more signing issues.

Btw for all my integrations requiring OAuth I've used [this](http://oauth.riaforge.org/) library and didn't have any signing issues as with LinkedIn API.

Comment: Lucas, I started using linkedin-j to implement my API connector, but once I finished the OAuth implementation and moved onto the API methods, I kept getting this error: `
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index`. I was wondering if you dealt with it, and how you got passed it?

Comment: Which zip did you get from here http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/downloads/list ? Should get linkedin-j-1.0.415-binary.zip or the 1.0.429 beta binaries. Get *all* the JARs from there and put them where they should be on your server (depends on setup, usually in #server.ColdFusion.ROOTDIR#\lib\). Then you need to restart the CF. From the error you posted it seems that one of the JARs is missing.

Comment: I am actually using JavaLoader and had to recompile the linkedin-j JAR to include some special things for JAXB to work properly. It was in Issue #53 on the issues page.